# DIL IC for simple non-volatile memory

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos, eeprom, non-volatile-memory

Can anyone suggest a DIL IC where I can store a couple bits of memory without having to use a complicated interface like serial, I2C, and etc. I want to be able to store at least 2 bits of memory to about 16 bits. An interface like this: http://pdf.datasheetarchive.com/datasheetsmain/Datasheets-X2/DSA848000-34.pdf
(Unfortunately that IC does not exist anymore, but that was RAM anyways)
...is the kind I'm looking for, just except that the memory is permanent. I used a 4013 to try to store permanent memory and it seemed like it worked (after setting Q to be on, disconnecting the battery for a day and coming back to see it at the same state) but sometimes it screwed up and forgot.

Also I do not want an answer that suggests me to program a PIC or something as such to behave as a EEPROM/Flash storage device. I'm aware of that being an option but I'm not too keen with that.

Comment: Oh well what is the point of downvoting on a post made 2 months ago? Although off topic, I'm pretty sure it can come in handy for other people in specific cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use something simple like a DIPswitch, you could use a parallel EEPROM, some of which are available even today.

Eg. AT28C64. Just ignore the 99.98% of the memory you won't be using.

Comment: Nice find. I will accept more answers in case other people have other IC recommendations.

Comment: Now...  I have trouble finding where I can buy the IC. Everything on eBay seems so fake.

Comment: @Bradman175 - Then stop looking for the parts on eBay. Check out the reputable suppliers such as Digikey and Mouser. BTW Mouser has several thousand of the AT28C64 in stock in 28-pin DIP package for less than 4USD each.

Comment: Shipping costs...

Comment: There are electronics retailers that operate in your country. Try for example au.element14.com. They also have the AT28C64 although price is about 2x higher.

Comment: Digikey has 1,147 in stock @USD 3.52 in 10's, in the old DIP package even.

Comment: Element14 is good for me. Price is only a teensy bit higher compared to mouser. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, this is about the only answer any longer -- Ramtron made some really cute F-RAM "state saver" parts, but they got [discontinued](http://www.cypress.com/knowledge-base-article/nonvolatile-state-saver-devices-kba203630) :/